# C# display IP location in map

Tags: c#, dictionary, ip

I'm making a simple http server and I want to add a world map feature, that displays client geo location.

I got two questions:

1. Is there a way to find out lat/lon of an IP address without using sites like ip2location.com?
2. How can I geographically display a point on an image(world map) with giving lat,lon as an input parameter? is there a formula for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to find out lat/lon of an IP address without using sites like ip2location.com?

No, unless you create and host your own database.

> How can I geographically display a point on an image(world map) with
>   giving lat,lon as an input parameter? is there a formula for that?

Both Google and Bing Maps provide such functionality. Here's [an example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/map-markers.html) with Google Maps which allows you to place markers on a map given their latitude and longitude.

---

UPDATE:

You could use a [Mercator Projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) to place a point given latitude and longitude. You may take a look at the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx) which explains the technique.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a way to do this without any external sites.

Comment: @user1015551, I am afraid that this would be quite a lot of work. It's possible but you will need a huge database storing all the mapping and geo-location functionalities. That's the reason why such services exist in the cloud. So that they can be reused without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I mean I don't mind using ip2location, but for mapping, like all I need to do is to a function that converts long,lat to x,y does that involve long code?

Comment: @user1015551, what do you mean by `x, y`?

Comment: I need a function that accepts two arguments - lat/lon. Calculates x and y cordinates on a image of a world map and places a dot in there.

Comment: @user1015551, you could use a [Mercator Projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection). I have updated my answer to provide an article which explains it in more details.